# Помогите избавиться от цикла в реляционной схеме БД

Tags: база-данных, проектирование

Задача следующая:
- В преподавателя имеются групы, в которых он преподает
- В группе состоят студенты
- Также есть предметы, которые преподаются в группе
- Нужно сохранять оценку студента по предметам

Я пришел к такому решению:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите можна ли как-то избавиться от цикла? Или цикл в этой ситуации единственное решение.

Comment: Что какая таблица обозначает? Где здесь преподаватели? Может ли один предмет читаться разными преподавателями? Может ли у студента не быть (быть больше одной) оценки по предмету?

Comment: users - преподаватели. Один предмет не может читаться разными преподавателями. У студента 0,1 или более оценок.

Comment: Тогда схема правильна. Только я бы переименовал поле created_by в user_id